# A webpage inside a webpage: what HTML element can do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website updater. My idea is to have certain HTML elements be part of the class **updatable**. I will then change each element with that class to a textarea element. That way it can be updated.

What I want to do is divide my updater.html into 2 areas, the left side will have a select element (with a list of page names) the right side will show/load a specific webpage inside the updater.html webpage.

Is it possible to do this & what HTML element would I need to do this? Is it a frame or iframe (What about object or is that only for HTML5)? Is an iframe cross browser? My aim is to have this work on IE, FireFox, Chrome & Safari.

**What do you think would be the best HTML element to do this with? Also will the newly loaded HTML page(WITH its css style sheet) affect the updater.html layout (because it has a different css style sheet)?**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="updaterSection">
          <select>
            <option> home </option>
             ...
          </select>
        </td>

        <td class="updatableWebpage">
          <!-- What would you put here? -->
        </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to use an **iframe** to accomplish this task.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="updaterSection">
                    <select>
                        <option> home </option>
                        ...
                        </select>
                </td>
                <td class="updatableWebpage">
                    <iframe src="yourwebpage.html" id="webpage">
                    </iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried the getElementById version before and had trouble with it because src isn't a property of every object or some reason like that. Since then i've always used window.frames['webpage'].src.

Comment: Is the trouble you are having with getElementById that the webpage isn't changing when you select one of the options, or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use an iframe for that. As below

```
<iframe src="webpage2.html"></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

iframes are cross browser and will work in this case.  they also will contain their own styles that wont affect the page outside the iframe.